# Integrating a non-ASP.NET application with IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, iis

Basically I want to integrate an application written in C# with IIS, and this application is not created with ASP.NET but has the ability to output HTML - so what I'm after is hooking into IIS somehow and catching all requests to a "Web Site" (IIS-concept) and allowing my custom application to handle them.

I honestly have *no idea* where to even start looking at this sort of thing, so any help is appriciated.

**tl;dr**-version: How would I go about creating something aching to an apache module for IIS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this by [creating an HttpHandler](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6962/0/page/2).

Comment: Sort of yes, since it requires .NET.  It is a whole lot easier to write an HttpHandler than it is to roll your own ISAPI filter.